# Allow exim to send FROM any catch-all address

Tags: linux, email, smtp, exim

I have a domain shrimp.foo already setup at the MX to route all incoming mail addresses (*@shrimp.foo) to one particular mailbox the ISP provides for IMAP, POP, webmail, etc.:  bubba@shrimp.foo

Tested sending TO *random-address*@shrimp.foo works.

Back on my Linux Ubuntu box, using the SMTP credentials, I can already send out mail as bubba@shrimp.foo, no problem.

Problem is, how do I send FROM an arbitrarily different address other than bubba@, but still the same domain somethingelse**@shrimp.foo**?
My attempts using the `mail` command error:

```
Sender address rejected: not owned by user
```

In my  **/etc/exim4/passwd.client**

```
# https://poczta.nazwa.pl/
shrimp.foo:bubba@shrimp.foo:password
*.shrimp.foo:bubba@shrimp.foo:password
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I figured it out. Not sure which change mattered most for this but:

in **/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf**

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost'
dc_smarthost='smtp.englishetc.pl::587'
```

The ::587 wasn't obvious to me.

in **/etc/exim4/passwd.client**

```
# https://poczta.nazwa.pl/
englishetc.pl:bubba@englishetc.pl:passwd
smtp.englishetc.pl:bubba@englishetc.pl:passwd
^smtp[0-9]*.englishetc.pl:bubba@englishetc.pl:passwd
*.englishetc.pl:bubba@englishetc.pl:passwd
```